# In Codeigniter, how to validate radio buttons (without "checked")?

Tags: php, codeigniter, radio-button, validation

In Codeigniter, I would like to validate radio buttons but I don't want to select one when the user loads the page (I mean **no "checked" attribute**).

This is what I have done so far...

My view file:

```
<?=validation_errors()?>
<form action="step1" method="post">
    <input name="food" type="radio" value="1" <?=set_radio('food', '1')?> />
    <input name="food" type="radio" value="2" <?=set_radio('food', '2')?> />
    <input name="food" type="radio" value="3" <?=set_radio('food', '3')?> />
</form>
```

My controller file:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('food', 'food', 'required');
if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) redirect('step2');
```

The error message only appears if I add a field like an `<input type="text">`. But my wish is to have only 3 radio buttons and an error message if none are selected.

Do you know how to do that?

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed us what you already tried. Anyway, use this link as a guide: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: Here is the answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034185/repopulate-radio-buttons-on-failed-validation

Comment: @stefandoorn Code added. Thanks but I already use this page of the guide :)

Comment: @Timur I said I don't want to have any checked radio button and the two answsers of this topic gives TRUE (checked) as third argument for set_radio function.

Answer (score 3):

"***required*** *validation rule* does not return error message when the form contains radio buttons only", because of CodeIgniter 2 bug. See details here - https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/138 .

I fixed it simply by adding hidden field e.g. `<input type="hidden" value="true" name="fix_radio_required">`

Comment: Has this been fixed by now or do you still need to add the hidden field?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried checking for the ON status?

```
if($this->input->post('food') === 'on')
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach worked well for us.

```
<?php
$member_type = 1;
    if(isset($_POST['member_type'])){ 
        $member_type = $_POST['member_type'];
    }
    echo form_radio("member_type", 1, $member_type == 1 ? TRUE : FALSE,' id="member_type" class="form-control"');

    echo form_radio("member_type", 2, $member_type == 2 ? TRUE : FALSE,' id="member_type" class="form-control"');
?>
```

To expand on what Andriy wrote we'll take the value of the submitted radio button and then do a TRUE or FALSE to set the checked value.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Form Validation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html) library, you can achieve that with the following:

**Controller**

```
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('', '<br>');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('type', '<b>Type</b>', 'trim|required|maxlength[1]|xss_clean');
```

**View**

```
<label for="type_1">Is this type one, two or three? <b style="color: red">*</b></label></td>

<input type="radio" name="type" id="type_1"<?php echo set_radio('type', '1'); ?> value="1"><label for="type_1">One</label> &nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="type" id="type_2"<?php echo set_radio('type', '2'); ?> value="2"><label for="type_2">Two</label>
<input type="radio" name="type" id="type_3"<?php echo set_radio('type', '3'); ?> value="3"><label for="type_3">Three</label>
<span style="color: red; font-weight: bold"><?php echo form_error('type'); ?><?php echo isset($errors['type']) ? $errors['type'] : '' ?></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Form Validation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html):

Controller:

```
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('food', 'Radio button', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'Error message');
    }
```

Here you set rules for your radio buttons:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('food', 'Radio button', 'required');
```

'food' means name of your radio button.

'Radio button' - "human" name for this field

'required' - validation rule for this form field

With $this->form_validation->run() you run form validation library arnd check if your form passed (TRUE/FALSE).

View:

```
<?=validation_errors()?>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="radio" name="food" value="1">
        <input type="radio" name="food" value="2">
        <input type="radio" name="food" value="3">

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

Here is form with 3 radio buttons with same name 'radio' as used in controller.

Comment: What do you mean by type="food" ??? Except this stange thing, you can observ the rest of your code is very similar to mine. It doesn't help me very much... :/

Comment: ooops.. my bad. type is "radio" name="food" :) sorry

Comment: ok, at first I misunderstood your problem. maybe now it's what you need?

Comment: Damn, it doesn't work either... Can you try it and tell me if it works? I can't get this error message with only radio buttons. If I add another field like a text field it works, but not only with radio buttons. Unfortunately, I don't understand why :(

Answer (score 0):

**View File**

```
<?php echo form_error('gender')?>
<form name="frm" method="post">
<input type="radio" value="m" name="gender" /> Male <br />
<input type="radio" value="f" name="gender" /> Female <br />
<input type="radio" value="o" name="gender" /> Other
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="btn" />
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('field' => 'gender', 'label' => 'Gender', 'rules' => 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run()==TRUE)
    {
        echo "hello wordl"; exit;
    }
    //Your view loading script..
}
```